# FBX importing and armatures

Tags: armature, import, .fbx

Hello i was wondering if there is a way to fix the armatures for FBX files

[image]

As you can see, the armatures is a mess, but i can still move it correctly. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi. If they're working correctly what are you trying to fix? The size of the bones?

Comment: The size and the direction they are pointing at seems wrong, shouldn't the armature be inside the model and not poking out the model?